# XCode / Objective C conditional breakpoint based on caller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nslog

Ok, i have a requirement to set a breakpoint that only gets "hit" when a method is (or is not) called by a specific object and/or selector

the easiest way i can think of doing that is if there were some compiler macro (like _cmd) that unwinds the stack and returns the id and selector of the immediate caller of the current method.

eg assuming the majical macros were _cmd_caller_id & _cmd_caller_sel) -

```
if ( (_cmd_caller_id == self) && (_cmd_caller_sel != @selector(some_method:signature:) ) {
   NSLog(@"called by %@ - hitting breakpoint",NSStringFromSelector(_cmd_caller_sel));
}
```

(and you would put a break point on the line containing the NSLog(...); );

the reason being i have a method that is called many times, an i need to be able to set up a  more complex set of conditions than i have described above to set a trap to determine what method is calling the offending method and when.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your breakpoint at the calling site, with a condition on the breakpoint (e.g. self == whatever)

Comment: yeah, i have solved that issue another way (working backwards). however, in some cases you don't have source to the calling site - i was trying to track down where a spurious retain was coming from. it would be nice to be able to unwind the stack, but i guess that's for another day.

Comment: If you want to figure out where extra retains are coming from, use Instruments, not GDB.

Comment: normally i'd agree with you, however i am working on something that requires realtime analysis. i.e the performance hit of instruments is not acceptable. (ie am doing a lot of number crunching of real time audio samples ahead of playback)